# Using outputs from one function as inputs in another

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

Currently trying to write a function which is using the outputs of a previous function. The outputs are as follows:

```
f(x) = exp(x) -3*x.^2
fp(x) = exp(x) -6*x
fpp(x) = exp(x) -6
```

The new function is:

```
x_new = x - 2*(f(x))*(fp(x)) / 2*(fp(x).^2) -(f(x))*(fpp(x))
```

Tried to write `[f,fp,fpp] = fun(x)` because it worked for me in a script file earlier but now its saying

> error not enough input arguments

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

The original question:

[image: The question]

Comment: I don't really understand what is called how. And what should the return values `f`, `fp` and `fpp` mean if there is only `x_new`? And if your function is `fun`, shouln't it be `fun(x)` instead?

Comment: `f`,`fp`,and `fpp` are the outputs from the first function in symbolic form. `x_new` is the output of the second function. yes meant `fun(x)`, typo unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it is not working but I think code below works well for me:

```
function[f,fp,fpp,x_new]=fun(x) 
f=exp(x) -3*x.^2 ;
fp=exp(x) -6*x ;
fpp=exp(x) -6;
x_new= x - 2*(f)*(fp) / 2*(fp.^2) -(f)*(fpp);
return


x=1234;
for ind=1:10
  [f,fp,fpp,x]=fun(x);
end
```

Comment: assuming it is an iteration :)

Comment: it is an iteration. x_new is the only output argument of the second function so should `function[f,fp,fpp,x_new]=fun(x)` not read `function[x_new]=halley(fun,x,acc)`? FYI `halley` is the name of the second function, `fun` is the name of the first function(whose outputs are `f`,`fp`,`fpp`. `acc` is a given value and `x` is the interval `[-5 5]`. `acc` isn't used in the function instead it is used in a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the math here, but you need only one function, that should look something like this:

```
function r = halley(fun,x0,acc)
syms x
fp = diff(fun);
fpp = diff(fp);
x_new = symfun(x - 2*(fun(x))*(fp(x)) / 2*(fp(x).^2) -(fun(x))*(fpp(x)),x);
xold = x0;
xnew = x_new(xold);
while abs(fun(xold)) < acc && abs(xold-xnew) > acc
    tmp = xnew;
    xnew = x_new(xold);
    xold = tmp;
end
r = xnew;
end
```

and then you call it from a script with another function as input:

```
acc = 1.0e-8;
x0 = -5;
syms x
fun = symfun(exp(x) -3*x.^2 +1,x);
r = halley(fun,x0,acc)
```

however, in this exercise it says that the input of the function should be a function handle, like `@fun`, so maybe you should not use symbolic math?
I hope this makes things clearer, though I don't know how this method should work.

Comment: How do I then include a start point for the `x` values at `-5` and use a while loop to stop the function when the difference between succesive `x` values is less than the input `acc` (which has value `1.0e -8`) and also when `abs(fun(x))< acc`. Its a previous exam paper I'm using as practice. Is it alright to post it here? Not sure as I'm a new user. Might be easier than me explaining.

Comment: `fun(x)` has 3 outputs, so `abs(fun(x))< acc` has no clear meaning to me.

Comment: I think you should add more details to your question, because it is not clear what is  the purpose of all this, are `acc` and `-5` inputs to `halley`? what should be the output?

Comment: when I try to run this starting from `-5`, I get `-Inf` very quickly.

Comment: screen grap of the question, Hope this clears it up.

Comment: @Matlabrookie Well, I'm not familiar with this math, but I hope my edit will make the using of functions a little clearer.

Comment: need to use symbolic math earlier in the question.. Is there anyway to use a function handle for a symbolic function?